# How to sort how you want the the data from firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore with *lessons*, see the picture below, I get from the firestore the title property from each object and display it in the browser, but everytime I refresh the website the lessons are sorted by how they want, why is that happening? I want to sort them how I want, I want to start with 'Introduction' and so on, how can I do that? I think the `orderBy()` is not working here.

[image: firestore order]

As you see in the image above, the order in the firestore is alphabetical, but in my page is sorted by its own, see the picture below.

[image: website worder]

I want the result to be by in a specific order, for example we have the following titles, these titles are from the firestore: "Display", "Introduction", "Alignment", my problem is that these 3 titles are in a new order every time I refresh the website, I want them to be: "Introduction", "Alignment", "Display". In my case I have more titles but this is what's happening, I don't know how to align them how I want or even alphabetical if is possible.

Below is the code that I used to get the data from firestore:

```
useEffect(() => {
  
    db.collection("users")

      .doc(`${user.uid}`)
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        const allData = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id };
        const intoArray = Object.entries(allData);
        intoArray.sort(); // I used sort here because I had the same problem 
                          // (every time a new order) with the 
                          // data when I converted it to an array

        const getCSSLessons = intoArray[0][1];
        const cssData = Object.values(getCSSLessons);
        setCss(cssData);

        const getHTMLLessons = intoArray[1][1];
        const htmlData = Object.values(getHTMLLessons);
        setHtml(htmlData);

        const getResLessons = intoArray[3][1];
        const resData = Object.values(getResLessons);
        setRes(resData);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));

  }, [user]);
```

I tried using `sort()`, for a variable (htmlData) but its not working.
Also, I use `map()` to display them, if this helps you to answer to my question.

Comment: I'm unclear what isn't working the way you expect.  I don't know what this means: "*the lessons are sorted by how they want*".  Please edit your question to explain in more detail what you expect and how that's different than what's actually happening.  You will probably have to write more clear code to sort the array by whatever requirement you have.

Comment: As you see in the picture from the actual website, the result is starting with "Rules", when I refresh the website will be other title, is not in a exact order, and this is happening every time I refresh the website, a new order for the results is appearing.

Comment: You're not defining the order in which Firebase should present the data to your app. You can either include a sort option when getting the documents OR sort in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing something unnecessary as you see in the first picture I had a main object `css` and in that object I had sub-objects like `alignment` and in the sub object I had the properties that I want to display, that sub object was unncessary, istead of sub objects with a pre defined name, I let the firebase to count the sub objects and add as a name a number and the order is the same as I wanted to be.

[image]

The code that I used to add data to firebase:

```
fire
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((cred) => {
        return db
          .collection("users")
          .doc(cred.user.uid) 
          .set({
            
           css: [
              {
                title: "Introduction",
                path: "/css3/introduction",
              },
              {
                title: "Priority",
                path: "/css3/priority",
              },
          
            ],

           });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `sort` without any argument, it will sort array elements alphabetically. It looks like your array elements are arrays, which will end with unexpected behaviors. Use `sort` argument to ensure it uses your own sorting rules. For example:

```js
const intoArray = Object
  .entries(allData)
  // I don't know what should be the sorting algorithm
  // As an example, I consider each element (`a` and `b`) to 
  // be arrays and compare both first element as a Number
  .sort( (a, b) => a[0] - b[0])
```

#### Edit

A more secure way to find elements in an array is to use `find`:

```js
const getCSSLessons = intoArray[0]
  .find( element => element.name === 'CSS Lessons');
```

Comment: the problem is not there, in the `intoArray` i'm only converting the data from firestore which is an object into an array, I had the same problem where the items from the array was on a new order every time I was refreshing the website but with only `sort()` it worked, my problem is on `cssData` `htmlData` and `resData` variables, if i'm console logging these variables I'm getting a new order for the items that are in each variable every time I'm refresing, the sort() method is not really working.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(allData)`?

Comment: Is actually the data from firestore, the first image from the post, I get 3 objects, because I have 3 objects in the firestore document, and the items from each object is aligned alphabetical. I convert the object into an array with the `intoArray` variable and the items are sorted alphabetical, until now is good, the value for `intoArray` varibale is 3 arrays with those objects from the firestore document, i'm getting each array with the a specific variable, example: `getCSSLessons` , then I'm getting the value also in an array from the `getCSSLessons` variable so I can map it into the web.

Comment: the problem is when I'm displaying the result every time I refresh the page a new order for the items from `cssData` is applied (this happens for all 3 documents, `resData` and `htmlData`, I want to know how can I set a specific order.

Comment: Have you tried to use `sort` into each sub-array?

Comment: Or even better, don't use indexes: find the right element with `find`: `const getCSSLessons = intoArray[0].find( element => element.name === 'CSS Lessons')`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225225/discussion-between-tudor-alexandru-and-emi).